# How to make author box like this & add after every post?

Tags: content

I want to make an author box like this :
[image]

```
<table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">About Author</span>&nbsp;</b>
        <input type="hidden" name="stats" value="2498">
        </h3>you can be an author too, join mhktricks and show you skills</td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
        <a href="http://mhktricks.net/user-registration/" target="_blank">
        <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px; width:150px;" type="button" value="Join Us">
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>

        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 70 ); ?>
        </td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <span style="color: #555;font-size:20px;font-family: Open Sans;font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;">
        <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>
        </span>
        <br><div style="margin-left:1px;">
        <?php echo get_author_role(); ?>

        <span style="position:relative;top:1px;margin-left:5px;"><img src="http://i2.wp.com/codex.onhax.net/img/verified.png" height="12" width="12"></span>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;">
        <div style="margin-left: 3px;margin-top: -17px;border: #B8B8B8 1px solid;border-radius:2px;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;font-size:10px;">
        <?php the_author_posts(); ?> POSTS</div>';
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table><div style="margin-top:-12px;">&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:3px;margin-top:2px;padding-right:60px;">
        <?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?> 
        <a class="author-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
           View all posts by me 
        <?php get_the_author(); ?>
        <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>
        </a>        
        </div>
        </td>   
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr color="white">
        <hr color="white">
        <table style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;width:100%;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h3><b><span style="color: #555; ">Discussion</span></b></h3>
          share your knowledge.mind to help others</td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #ffffff;" align="right">
        <a href="#" class="show-comments">
        <input class="p2graybtn" style="height: 26px;" type="button" value="Toggle Comments">
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have made upto this but how to insert it in every post ?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested your code; but assuming it's correct and working well, edit your `single.php` file and insert this code just after the point where you end your post content and before the Comment Section starts.

I'd suggest to write this Author Box code in a separate file and then use `get_template_part` to insert the Author Box section in your Post. See [this function Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) if you're new to the `get_template_part` function.

Comment: When I add it in my single.php it appears below comment box & I can't add it in between , I am using P2 theme

Answer (score 0):

you can do with `the_content` filter.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20 );
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {

  if ( is_single() ) {
      $content = $content . "YOUR_HTML_FOR_BOX";
  }

  // Returns the content.
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working , please help

Answer (score 0):

Just add bellow code into function.php file.

```
function add_author_content($content)
{
  $author = get_the_author();
  $content = $content.' - '.$author;
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_author_content');
```

Comment: Where to add my code ?

Comment: Mentioned code add into 'function.php' add showing code into your page.php,single.php or other template 'apply_filters('the_content', $post_content);'

Comment: No I mean I want to add table in author box